# swrevealviewcontroller on top of viewcontroller objective c

Tags: objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using swrevealviewcontroller for slidemenu.
It is working properly.
Problem is when i swipe it push my mainviewcontroller to rightside and show the swrevealmenu on left. 
I want swrevealmenu should display on top of my mainviewcontroller.
Is there anyway to acheive this. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that logic of the swrevealviewcontroller is to put side menu as content view controller like parent of every views.

Maybe you should try REFrostedViewController to make menu above another view controller :
https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

Comment: i  agree. Is this achievable in SWRevealcontroller ?

Comment: I am not rly sure. I suspect that this change is difficult.